# Select code from tx_news tables from a particular category ordered by random

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

News extension don't provide order by random function only those fields:

```
orderByAllowed = sorting,author,uid,title,teaser,author,tstamp,crdate,datetime,categories.title
```

I want to select 6 news items from the news table that belong to category "category 6" ordered by random, and show  the title, teaser, and image on the front-end.

Is there a solution to do that with typoscript or so ?

Typo3 v7.6
tx_news v6.3

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it all by yourself.

In TypoScript you can do queries with the `CONTENT` object. It's just that you have to do the rendering by yourself.

You also can query the records from PHP - with your own rendering.

Comment: I don't know how to do this with the filter by category part and image rendering part.

Comment: the filter would be a join to `sys_category_record_mm` with appropriate `WHERE` condition. And images also are relations to a table (-> `sys_file_reference` -> `sys_file`)

Comment: Thank you, this porbably a good solution, client has changed his mind now, i will test this in future.